# Unauthorized Twitter Stream Sample

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter

I'm trying to learn Twitter API using LinqToTwitter. It works fine to connect to Twitter API but not Twitter Stream. As far as I can tell I need special rights to access the firehouse but the sample stream and the filter stream should be accessable. If that's true I can't seem to understand why I get "401 Unauthorized" with the following code:

```
        var auth = new ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer
    {
        Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
        {
            ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"],
            ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"],
        }
    };

    auth.Authorize();

    var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

    int count = 0;
    string response = "";
    (from strm in twitterCtx.Streaming
     where strm.Type == StreamingType.Filter &&
         strm.Track == query
     select strm)
    .StreamingCallback(strm =>
    {
        if (strm.Status != TwitterErrorStatus.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(strm.Error.ToString());
            return;
        }

        response += "<p>" + strm.Content + "</p>";

        if (count++ >= 2)
        {
            strm.CloseStream();
        }
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter streams don't support application-only authorization. Try the SingleUserAuthorizer. Also, a 401 error can happen for several reasons and you can review the [LINQ to Twitter FAQ](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20FAQ&referringTitle=Documentation) for help.